# how to export oracle DB table with complex CLOB data into bigquery through batch upload?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

We are currently using Apache sqoop once daily to export an oracle DB table containing a CLOB column into HDFS. As part of this we first map the CLOB column to java string(using --map-column-java) and have the imported data to be saved in the format of parquet. We have this scheduled as an oozie workflow.

There is a plan to move from apache hive to bigquery. I am not able to find a way to get this table into bigquery and would like help on the best approach to get this done.

If we go withreal time streaming from oracle DB into bigquery using google datastream, can you tell me if the clob column will get streamed correctly, as it has some malformed xml data (close to xml structure but might have some discrepancies in obeying the structure).

Another option i read was to have the table extracted as a csv file,and have it transferred to GCS and have the bigquery table refer it there.But since mydata in CLOB column is very large and is wild with multiple commas and special chsracters in between, i think there will be issues with parsing or exporting. Any options to do it in parquet or ORC formats?

The preferred approach is to have a scheduled batch upload performed daily from oracle to bigquery. Appreciate any inputs on how to achieve the same.

Comment: BigQuery can load Parquet and ORC data with different compression types. For more information take a look at these links : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet and https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-orc

Comment: Yeah. I noticed that but i dont know of a way to convert the oracle table data in ORC or Parquet format in a scheduled manner. Do you know of any way to do it? If so, i can generate ORC or Parquet load it into GCS and have them read in Bigquery.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert CLOB data from Oracle DB to desired format like ORC, Parquet, TSV, Avro files through [Enterprise Flexter](https://sonra.io/xml/converting-xml-documents-from-an-oracle-clob-to-a-relational-format/).
Also, you can refer to [this](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/cloud-and-hybrid/etl-on-premises-oracle-data-to-google-bigquery-using-google-cloud-dataflow) on how to ingest on-premises Oracle data with Google Cloud Dataflow via JDBC, using the Hybrid Data Pipeline On-Premises Connector.

**For your other query moving from apache hive to bigquery-**

The fastest way to import to BQ is using GCP resources. Dataflow is a scalable solution to read and write. Dataproc is also another option that is more flexible and you can use more open source stacks to read from the Hive cluster.

You can also use this Dataflow [template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#apache-hive-to-bigquery), which would require a connection to be established directly between the Dataflow workers and the Apache Hive nodes.

There is also a plugin for moving data from Hive into BigQuery which utilises GCS as a temporary storage and uses BigQuery Storage API to [move data](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hive-bigquery-storage-handler) to BigQuery.

You can also use [Cloud SQL](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/tools/hive-bigquery) to migrate your Hive data to BigQuery.